# When calling from my phone - how do I hide my caller id when calling people that are not in my contacts?

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts, 6.0-marshmallow, caller-id, oneplus-3

I have switched phone brands (my last phone ― a Lumia 1020 ― had this option) and now I have a One Plus 3 now (with root and fully updated).

How can I make sure that when calling someone, my number is hidden for non-contacts?

I can't seem to find the setting in Android to show my number only to people in my contacts when calling: I have searched all accessible setting menu's in my phone for this and yet I can only find to permanently hide or show my number.

I know it can be done on a per-call basis by prefixing the callee's number with operator codes like `#31#`, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I was going to publish a duplicate question but the similar questions list prevented me. ;) When I had my Windows Mobile 5 device (iPAQ hw6915) I used to have the `Send Caller Id` option set to "Contacts Only", meaning that when calling somebody whose number was not on my address book they would get a `Private`/`Anonymous`/`Unknown` call. Now that I got a OnePlus 3 it is upsetting that such a simple and old option is missing on such a modern device. I starred the question. Anyways we could try asking in the official forums, maybe the developers will add it? Also, the Cyanogen Mod may have it.

Comment: Deleted my answer suggesting that app - it doesn't seem to work for my brother in USA on 3  different phones !